# Testing Grafana alert returns "Failed to test the rule" with 500 - Internal Server Error response

Tags: amazon-web-services, prometheus, grafana, prometheus-alertmanager

I'm trying to set up alerts on one of my graphs. I'm using AMG (Amazon Managed Grafana). However, I'm getting "Failed to test the rule" notification. When I inspect HTTP response, it shows

```
Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error

{"message":"Failed to test rule"}
```

URL

```
https://g-39e1d60d36.grafana-workspace.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/api/alerts/test
```

Here is my alert setup (even If I try something super simple, still getting the same issue):
[image]

To me, it seems like Grafana internal error/bug, does anyone experience a similar issue and know the potential resolution?

Comment: Check Grafana logs

Comment: Didi you managed to figure out what was the problem?

Comment: @TariqN Did this get resolved? We have the same issue on our managed Grafana on AWS. Immediately fails with simple alerts.

Comment: Yeah, going back to this question, I manage to resolve it in the same way some time ago. I added a bit more context, but your answer is totally correct.

Answer (score 2):

For us the solution was to not set the datasource dynamically from the environment variable we added in the interface. When we moved the target query to a fixed datasource, it all worked ok.

Comment: I had a similar problem and solved it in the same way

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved after I changed the data source of the query from a defined variable e.g `${PrometheusSource}` to a specific source instance `PrometheusProduction`. Seems like Grafana has some issues when setting up an alert for the query where the data source is a predefined variable.

For more context, I'm posting a screenshot from the Grafana dashboard:

[image]

After this change, the mentioned issue is not appearing anymore.